# Saved custom model doesn't returns it's id

Tags: magento2, model, setup, repository

I have a table with only 2 fields: **`id` (primary key) and `name`**. I've created a model for it, repository model.

In my repository model, there is a method save. I'm trying to create a new record in my table, executing:

```
$model = `$this->modelFactory->create();
$model->setName('some name');
$this->modelRepository->save($model);
```

Model saves succefully, but, when i try to get an id of created model, it returns null, so i have only `name` inside of model (`$model->getName()` => 'some name', `$model->getId()` => null)

So, how do I get new record id?

**P.S. New record appears in DB with correct id.**

There is a constructor of resource model:

```
/**
 * Initialize resource model and define main table
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('catalog_motorbike_vendors', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Please check your IntallSchema script, field `id` primary key must have `'identity' => true` or `'auto_increment' => true` for save autoincrement value

Comment: Can you share the constructor of your resourcemodel?

Comment: Yes, it has `'auto_inctement'=> true`. And it table i see correct ids for new entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a mistake in my own code. There was not implemented method `setId()` in my Model class.